# Suppression State Error LNK1000 Issue after changing code and removing it doesn't fix it

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I changed a couple lines of code, Heres the error list, Can Anyone Help me out with this? Its happened on a couple other projects too,
Im using VS community 2015.

```
1>  AES.obj : MSIL .netmodule or module compiled with /GL found; restarting link with /LTCG; add /LTCG to the link command line to improve linker performance
1>cryptlib.lib(modes.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/OPT:LBR' specification
1>  Generating code
1>e:\dxd\Loader\clogin.cpp(86): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 249)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>
1>e:\dxd\Loader\clogin.cpp(3): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c', line 249)
1>   To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
1>  Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>   Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>
1>
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1000: Internal error during IMAGE::BuildImage
1>
1>    Version 14.00.23918.0
1>
1>    ExceptionCode            = C0000005
1>    ExceptionFlags           = 00000000
1>    ExceptionAddress         = 50959ED2 (50890000) "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC\bin\c2.dll"
1>    NumberParameters         = 00000002
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 0] = 00000000
1>    ExceptionInformation[ 1] = 00000034
1>
1>  CONTEXT:
1>    Eax    = 00000039  Esp    = 0018E7C0
1>    Ebx    = 09D123BC  Ebp    = 0018E7EC
1>    Ecx    = 006A7FD0  Esi    = 00000000
1>    Edx    = 09D123BC  Edi    = 00000005
1>    Eip    = 50959ED2  EFlags = 00010216
1>    SegCs  = 00000023  SegDs  = 0000002B
1>    SegSs  = 0000002B  SegEs  = 0000002B
1>    SegFs  = 00000053  SegGs  = 0000002B
1>    Dr0    = 00000000  Dr3    = 00000000
1>    Dr1    = 00000000  Dr6    = 00000000
1>    Dr2    = 00000000  Dr7    = 00000000
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Rebuild the program and see if the linker error goes away.

Comment: Already Done that and clean the solution, the issue is very weird and its only happened on this version of VS, Believe me i've tried everything I could to my knowledge to fix this to no avail, this is my last resort.

Comment: Try to turn off the incremental linking (it's in the project settings).  I have had similar errors like this, and fixed by either linking again or rebuilding.  Don't know what causes it, but there seems to be bugs in the link phase.

Comment: I have already disabled this, to no avail.

Comment: Get rid of the /GL, /OPT:LBR, /LTCG and any other option for link time code generation.

Comment: This has also already been done on my end to no avail.

Comment: I'm not sure what service pack VS 2015 Community is up to (I know that VS 2015 released Update 3 recently), but I would ensure you're using the latest update for VS 2015.

Comment: /GL was on as @1201Programalarm had stated but there is still an issue in the compiler, but the Imagebase issue has been corrected